# Use Automator to drop one letter in the naming

Tags: automator

I've a kind of download-setup on my Mac and it does an excellent job downloading all the files I need. But for some reason the setup is renaming my files with "*Title 9x88 Name*". And I would like to drop this one "x" whenever a new files is detected in the directory.

Everything works perfect in Automator, except for the dropping the 1 letter.

[image]

I know Automator doesn't support wildcards, but is there any other way in how to drop the single *X* in the naming?
I'm open for every creative solution (shell scripts too).

Comment: Perhaps solving the root problem - why the file gets renamed with a 'x' in the middle - would be a better exercise than writing a kludgy work-around. Tell us what the download setup is and perhaps we can all tackle it together.

Comment: It's Sickbeard. But I don't know if this issue is discussable on this forum :)

Comment: Indeed ... perhaps not. Another solution would be to look at the utility app A Better Finder Rename, or learn a bit of regex and some shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Run Shell Script action like this:

[image]

`for f in *;do [[ $f =~ (.+ [0-9]+)x([0-9]+ .+) ]]&&mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";done;exit 0`

Or if the filenames don't contain other x characters, you could replace the script with `for f in *;do mv "$f" "${f/x/}";done`.